# Javascript: Get div inside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs nested like so:

```
<div id="upper">
<div id="lower" name="moo">
</div>
</div>
```

How would I, using jQuery or JavaScript alone, can I get the name of that lower nested div?

Comment: What have you tried? There's a lot of ways, depending on what you need. OT: 'name' is not an allowed attribute for a div AFAIK.

Comment: I don't care if it's allowed, I'm just using it to store data javascript can access easily.

Comment: then you might want to look at using `data-` attributes. For example: `<div id="lower" data-name="moo"></div>`. That's perfectly valid HTML5. Also, you can use the `$.data()` function to retrieve all of the data attributes set on an element.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var nameValue = $('#lower').attr('name');
```

But if you really want to use the outer `div` to select the inner one:

```
var nameValue = $('#upper > div').attr('name');
```

Or

```
var nameValue = $('#upper #lower').attr('name');
```

Or

```
var nameValue = $('#upper').find('#lower').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.children`.

http://api.jquery.com/children/